# How to validate field type checkboxes in system.xml

Tags: system.xml

I am using magento 1.9.
In my custome module,  In system.xml added field type checkboxes.

```
<show_featuredproduct translate="label">
    <label>Show Featured Product On</label>
    <frontend_type>checkboxes</frontend_type>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_frequency</source_model>
    <validate>validate-one-required</validate>
    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
 </show_featuredproduct>
```

I want to add validation for this field. I used `<validate>validate-one-required</validate>` but its not working.
 Any Idea?

Comment: Can you confirm whether Magento is adding the `validate-one-required` class to the checkbox elements?

Comment: @ColinO'Dell - class not added to the element.

Comment: @PMB I noticed a prodblem with varien form and checkbox validation recently. Have a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/28524/158

Comment: @DavidManners - I used getClass. It shows validation message for every checkbox. Yes there is problem with validation.

Comment: I used multiple select drop down instead of checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

It's likely not working for 1 of 2 reasons:

#### 1. The class isn't being applied to the input elements.

If this the case, try using `<frontend_class>validate-one-required</frontend_class>` instead, and see whether that applies the class.

#### 2. The `validate-one-required` rule isn't working as expected.

You can try using `validate-one-required-by-name` instead, which Magento seems to use frequently with other sets of checkboxes.

Try one (or both) combinations, and hopefully that'll do the trick.

Comment: I tried both combinations not working

Comment: Try required-entry or validate-select

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want required field means

```
<validate>required-entry</validate>
<validate>validate-select</validate>
```

Refer this link [Here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/)

Comment: @Manikkandan  I tried for both. Both not working. Seems there is problem with the multiple check box validation.